# display foreignkey field in django template

Tags: django, templates, foreign-keys

I have models.py like below:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.user

class Student(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.user)

class Teacher(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.user)

class Complaint(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    complaint = models.TextField()
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s : %s" % (self.complaint)
```

How can I display teacher's name which is eventually stored in **class Profile**
What I get is a column **teacher_id** in **_complaint** table when I do

```
student_obj = Student.objects.get(name=user_profile_instance)
```

and then

```
compaint = student_obj.complaint_set.values()
```

in complaint.html

```
{{complaint.teacher_id}}
```

what I want is teacher name instead of id

Answer (score 7):

This should work -

```
{{ complaint.teacher.user.user.first_name }}
```

Comment: This answer should work, but keep in mind that in your `Complaint` model you are allowing `Teacher` to be null.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Please Update your style of coding to make your App Optimised

**Use**

```
student_obj = Student.objects.select_related().get(name=user_profile_instance)
```

The Above one will Cache Datas . After that each time when u call Datas from fields it Wont HIT your database :) , Hence Your App will Fly

**instead of**

```
student_obj = Student.objects.get(name=user_profile_instance)
```

and i'm Agreeing with @Bibhas Answer

```
{{ complaint.teacher.user.user.first_name }}
```

Teacher's Profile is Inheriting Django's Auth Model User

That wise

```
user.user.first_name
```